# why is the chemical potential included in the hamiltonian for a systeme coupeled to a particle reservoir

Tags: second-quantization, chemical-potential

I am beginning with second quantification language so i saw that if we are in grand canonical ensemble then:
$$
H=H_0 - \mu N
$$

naturally i thought that this $ \mu  $ would be included in the weight factor of the statistical average but i am surprised too find it in H, is it equivalent or is does this have a physical sens that i am not seeing ?

Comment: hint: what is the weight factor? hint2: how would you compute the internal energy?

Answer (score 5):

From [these Cornell lecture notes](http://www.physics.udel.edu/~bnikolic/QTTG/shared/reviews/brouwer_notes.pdf):

> Usually we will include the term −μN into the definition of the
>   Hamiltonian Ĥ, so that expressions for the thermal average in the
>   canonical and grand canonical ensembles are formally identical.